# Error using Filter and Projection in Objectify Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying to execute the below query using Objectify 5.1.8 :-

```
Query<Coupon> coupons = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(Coupon.class).filter("rewardPoints !=", "").project("code").distinct(true);
    for (Coupon coupon : coupons) {
        out.write(coupon.getCode());
    }
```

It is giving me an error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Inequality filter on rewardPoints must also be a group by property when group by properties are set.
```

Basically, what I wish to achieve is to perform a filter and project query alongside the distinct query on an entity.

Please let me know if there is something wrong with the query.

Note: rewardPoints is Indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Objectify but in the Google App Engine Datastore a [Projection query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries#Java_Using_projection_queries_in_Java) limits the returned results to just the column(s) specified. Using `distinct` is the same as [grouping](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries#Java_Grouping) and from the error message, it looks like you need to add `rewardPoints` to the projection in order to use the inequality filter and distinct at the same time.

Comment: Excellent! I use `python` on Google App Engine so the concepts are the same. I figured it was just a matter of translating it to the Objectify API.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Josh was right. I changed the query and it worked perfectly.

```
Query<Coupon> coupons = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(Coupon.class).filter("rewardPoints !=", "").project("rewardPoints").project("code").distinct(true);
```