# Using "DISTINCT" functionality in DataStoreIO.read with Apache Beam Java SDK

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am running a dataflow job (Apache Beam SDK 2.1.0 Java, Google dataflow runner) and I need to read from the Google DataStore "distinctly" on one particular property. (like the good old "DISTINCT" keyword in SQL).
Here is my code snippet :

```
Query.Builder q = Query.newBuilder();
q.addKindBuilder().setName("student-records");
q.addDistinctOn(PropertyReference.newBuilder().setName("studentId").build());
pipeline.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().read().withProjectId("project-id").withQuery(q.build()));
pipelilne.run();
```

When the pipeline runs, the read() fails due to the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Inequality filter on **key** must also be a group by property when group by properties are set., code=INVALID_ARGUMENT

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: This seems like a Datastore error rather than a Dataflow error. Have you looked at a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609684/error-using-filter-and-projection-in-objectify-google-datastore/32610795 ?

Comment: I tried adding "__key__" to the addDistinctOn function, but that didn`t seem to help . I thought the error message suggested that

Comment: Hmm I wonder if this is a bug in Datastore's query splitting. Are you able to execute the same query using plain Datastore API without Beam?

Comment: Can you try adding studentId in group by clause. Hope this helps.
As I am using BQ facing same problem. So instead we use group by clause. And is working as expected for BQ.

Comment: I am not very familiar yet with the Datastore V1 API, outside the context of dataflow . Will try out the suggestions mentioned ...